# Find Which Sites Where Solutions Are In-Use

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, stsadm

In SharePoint 2007, 2010, & 2013 how can I find out which sites the Features/Solutions that are installed in the Farm are actually in-use?